# The SharePoint item being crawled returned an error when requesting data from the web service

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, search, error

I'm running a SharePoint 2010 Enterprise where the search service application is giving me the following error:

*The SharePoint item being crawled returned an error when requesting data from the web service. ( Error from SharePoint site: *** Index was outside the bounds of the array. )*

There are quite a lot of items where this error is being shown. I've already performed a new full crawl, to no avail.

What else can I try to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at troubleshooting the hidden taxonomy list on the site throwing the error. This post mentions that may be the root of the error. You may be able to open some of the documents that use broken values and then save them back.

http://share-my-point-2010.blogspot.com/2012/09/error-from-sharepoint-site-index-was.html

There is also a repair script that may help resolve the issues.
http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Repair-Orphaned-Managed-824159e3